# Cannot get to download a PDF that was generated by Wicked PDF and then called it through angular $http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, rest, wicked-pdf

I call an API that returns a PDF generated by wicked_pdf gem. The pdf is returned in the response and I try to make a download after the file is generated but no download appears on the browser.
My controller looks like this:

```
      $http.get( Routes.get_products({format: "pdf"}),
    { 
      params:{
       params_object
      }
  }).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
       var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
       var href_config = ""
       if(format == 'csv'){
          href_config = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response.data);
       } else if (format == 'pdf'){
          href_config = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.data;
       }
       anchor.attr({
           href: href_config,
           target: '_blank',
           download: 'report.' + format
       })[0].click();
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

the controller is like this:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @product}
  format.csv { send_data @product.to_csv }
  format.pdf do 
    @report = @product.map_columns_to_export
    render  :pdf => "report", :template => 'product/product.pdf.erb', :layout => 'pdf'
  end
end
```

and the template product.pdf.erb is:

```
<html>
  <body>
<h1> Product </h1>
<table>
<thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Vendor</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>DOA</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @report.each do |line|%>  
      <tr>
          <td><%= line["ID"] %></td>
          <td><%= line["Vendor"] %></td>
          <td><%= line["Name"] %> </td>
          <td><%= line["Start Date"]%></td>
          <td><%= line["End Date"] %></td>
          <td><%= line["Price"] %></td>
          <td><%= line["DOA"] %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
```

The pdf returned in the response looks like this:

```
  PDF-1.4
  1 0 obj
  <<
  /Title (þÿ)
  /Creator (þÿwkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1)
  /Producer (þÿQt 4.8.6)
  /CreationDate (D:20160330163255-03'00')
  >>
  ...
```

I know base64 is not the encoding but utf-8 does not work either.

Nevertheless if I put the url in a new window the pdf is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to generate the pdf file and put it in public directory. In production app, amazon S3 is what you would want

Comment: Do you have to use a callback? You can instead just have a link that redirects the user to the pdf generation path (eg example.com/products/1.pdf). Trying to handle entire document responses in javascript adds a lot of complexity that can be avoided if you don't need any extra logic other than returning a file.